# cant use Apex bind-variable (String) to filter by recordId in SOQL

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, soql

I have a Lightning Component controller doing the following:

1. inserting a custom object `Audit__c` record via LightningDataService.
2. on successful insert calls a server-side controller method, passing one String parameter, `auditId`.

The Server-Side controller then queries the database for an `Audit__c` record `WHERE Id=: auditId`. This query is returning 0 rows. I've validated that the string being passed to filter the query is indeed the correct `Id` of the newly created `Audit__c` record.

Why isn't the SOQL query picking up the new `Audit__`c record even when being fed the right `Id` (as `String`). Is there some sort of casting issue that is causing Apex not to match the `String` filter value to a record `Id`?

**Client-Side Controller** (1 & 2)

```
component.find("auditCreator").saveRecord(function(saveResult) {
    if (saveResult.state === "SUCCESS" || saveResult.state === "DRAFT") {
        // record is saved successfully
        var resultsToast = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
        resultsToast.setParams({
            "title": "Saved",
            "message": "The audit was successfully initiated."
        });
        resultsToast.fire();

        var action = component.get("c.createAuditObjects");
        action.setParams({ auditId : JSON.stringify(saveResult.recordId)});
```

**Server-Side Controller**

```
public class initAuditReview {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static void createAuditObjects(String auditId){
        // auditId present
        System.debug('auditId is '+auditId);
        Audit__c parentAudit = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Audit__c WHERE Id=: auditId];
```

**Debug Log**

[image: debug log]

**Proof of record existence:**
[image: record page in salesforce]

Comment: Hi Nicholas, well asked question! As far as formatting goes, please note you can simply put empty lines between paragraphs (or a paragraph and a list/code block/etc.). You can also end a line with two spaces to create a line break. And use `1. ` instead of `1) ` to get `<ol>` formatting. See also: [Markdown Editing Help](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an issue with `auditId`. If you will check debug log you are getting Id as  `"a03f200000oVeZRAA0"`. So just remove `Json.stringify` from client-side controller:

```
    action.setParams({ auditId : saveResult.recordId});
```